# How to handle security on a wordpress site?

Tags: customization, security

I'm doing a draft of a WordPress site on localhost.

If I am using PHP snippets to do the sort of `back-end` functionality. How do I know that, when this goes to a real platform, the `php` code cannot be tampered with? How can I ensure that login information (password especially) is secure? Should I be doing password validation in the PHP snippets, or is there a more secure way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot be 100% sure you are safe.

Check this [Security reading from WordPress](https://wordpress.org/about/security/).

That been said, there are some things you can do.

- Keeping WordPress Updated
- Keeping theme and plugins Updated
- Use Strong Passwords
- You can use a Security Plugin, although it's arguable. When a client request it I use Sucuri.
- Change the Default “admin” username
- Limit Login Attempts
- Change WordPress Database Prefix
- Use double authentication

All that won't be enough but it will give intruders a hard time trying to get in.

Comment: Thank you for your concise answer! I will definitely being going through all these before the site goes live to give me some peace of mind.